# matrix multiplication in Opencv using c++

Tags: c++, opencv

Hi all I'm a rookie in C++ and Opencv as well. Kindly help me out on this.

I have a function (cv::aruco::estimatePoseSingleMarkers(markerCorners, markerLength, camMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs,tvecs); that gives pose of the marker w.r.t camera.
I used a for loop to print out the values of tvecs from the function.

> tvecs: [-0.0240248, 0.0161165, 0.052999]

When I print the size of tvecs it says the size is 1. But I think itś 1x3.

My requirement is to perform a matrix multiplication of the above mentioned tvces and a matrix of size [3x3].
How do I do this?
The following is the piece of code:

```
// Get frame and convert to OpenCV Mat
int openCVDataType=CV_8UC3;
cv::Mat image(cv::Size(pRequest->imageWidth.read(),pRequest->imageHeight.read()),openCVDataType,pRequest->imageData.read(),pRequest->imageLinePitch.read() );

//Undistort
cv::remap(image, imageUndist, map1, map2, CV_INTER_LINEAR);

//ArUco detection
cv::aruco::detectMarkers(imageUndist,dictionary,markerCorners,markerIds,detectorParams,rejectedCandidates);

if(markerIds.size() > 0) {

  cv::aruco::estimatePoseSingleMarkers(markerCorners, markerLength, camMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs,tvecs);


  for(unsigned int d = 0;d<markerIds.size();d++) {

    cout<<"tvecsss: "<<tvecs[d]<<endl;
    cout<<"tvecs: "<<tvecs[d].t()<<endl;

    cv::Mat rotMat;               
    cv::Rodrigues(rvecs[d],rotMat);
    rotMat = rotMat.t();
    cout<<"rotMat: "<<rotMat<<endl;
    cout<<"translation: "<<-tvecs[d]*rotMat<<endl;
  }
```

There's an error when I multiply tvecs[d]*rotMat. This the error:

```
mat.inl.hpp:1274: error: (-215:Assertion failed) data && dims <= 2 && 
(rows == 1 || cols == 1) && rows + cols - 1 == n && channels() == 1 in 
function 'operator cv::Vec<_Tp, m>'
```

Comment: Try to cast your vector to a matrix: `Mat(-tvecs[d]) * rotMat`

Comment: That didn't work too. This is the error I got:
matmul.cpp:1565: error: (-215:Assertion failed) a_size.width == len in function 'gemm'

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Do you maybe have a dimension mismatch? If you are multiplying matrix A with matrix B, A should have n rows and m columns and B should have m rows and k columns, to get the matrix C which is n times k.

Comment: How do I create a matrix containing elements of tvecs within the loop? I think that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this:

> -tvecs[d]*rotMat

into this:

> rotMat*-tvecs[d]

Tvec is 3x1 matrix and rotMat is 3x3 matrix

Comment: I get compilation error when I try that.
‘cv::Mat’ is not derived from ‘const cv::Matx<_Tp, m, n>’

Comment: Maybe try:
rotMat*cv::Mat(-tvecs[d])

Comment: This is due to the math rules of matrix multiplication.
The number of columns need to be equal when multiplying

Comment: Yeah I get that.  rotMat is 3x3 and Mat tvces[d].size() is 1x3.
I'm a bit skeptical about the convention in openCV in c++. Is it (cols,rows) or (rows,cols).